# AutoCompleteTextView drop down list is not hiding when an item selected for the first time

Tags: android, autocomplete

When a user types something in AutoCompleteTextView, I am fetching data from database in async task. I have addTextChangedListener with TextWatcher in AutoCompleteTextView.  The problem is that when 
the user selects an item from the suggested list, this data is entered into the text watcher but the drop down list even visible to the user. Because, when user select an item from drop down then TextWatcher.onTextChanged() gets called again and this call send a new request. This happens for the first time an item selected, if the user clicks the item again, the dropdown list won't show up.

So how to hide this drop down list when user select an item from the suggested list for the first time?

I have done this:

```
autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text);



     final TextWatcher yourTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            Log.d(TAG, "afterTextChanged:" + s.toString());
            afterTextChanged = s.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            Log.d(TAG, "beforeTextChanged:" + s.toString());
            beforeTextChanged = s.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            Log.e(TAG, "beforeTextChanged:" + beforeTextChanged + ",afterTextChanged:" + afterTextChanged + ",onTextChanged:" + s.toString());
            if (!beforeTextChanged.equals(s.toString())) {
                new doPopulate().execute(s.toString());
            }
        }
    };
```

**Logcat:** when an item is selected (Google) after typing "go"

```
beforeTextChanged:go
beforeTextChanged:go,afterTextChanged:go,onTextChanged:Google
afterTextChanged:Google
```

Comment: you don't need an AsyncTask and TextWatcher at all,  see my answer  here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858843/how-to-dynamically-add-suggestions-to-autocompletetextview-with-preserving-chara

Comment: why not? because its not necessary and makes your code too complex

Comment: @pskink, what if the database i am getting data is very large to search a text. would it make sense to use AsyncTask?

Comment: no,  AsyncTask is redundant here,  try to Log.d the Thread.currentThread() in runQuery() method from my example

Answer (score 0):

Keep a boolean flag for if the user selects, and add an onItemClickListener to your AutoCompleteTextView, ie

```
boolean selectedText = false;

autoComplete.setOnItemClickedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        selectedText = true;
    }
});
```

Then check the `selectedText` flag in your TextWatcher:

```
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        Log.e(TAG, "beforeTextChanged:" + beforeTextChanged + ",afterTextChanged:" + afterTextChanged + ",onTextChanged:" + s.toString());
        if (!beforeTextChanged.equals(s.toString()) && !selectedText) { //Here we check selectedText
            new doPopulate().execute(s.toString());
        }
        selectedText = false; //Clear selectedText flag
    }
```

Cheers

Comment: It won't work because onTextChanged is fired before onItemClick.

Comment: @CoKoder why do you insist on TextWatcher and AsyncTask?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line of code in your **onTextChanged** method :
`if(autoComplete.isPerformingCompletion()) {
            // An item has been selected from the list.
            return;
        }`

Answer (score 0):

i have added double spaces before the ArrayAdapter items of which displayed on Autocomplete dropdown and when user select an item from dropdown and when onTextChanged fired check the condition string is not equal to double spaces then execute asyn task.

ontextchanged code

```
autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);          
            autoComplete.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {         
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String SearchProd = s.toString(); 
                 if (SearchProd.length()>=2){
                     String SearchProdSpace=SearchProd.substring(0,2);                  

                        if(SearchProdSpace!="  " && itemselected==false)
                        {
                            try{
                             new GetProductData(SearchProd).execute(); 
                            }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();}
                       }
               }
                 itemselected=false;
            }
```

AsyncTask code

```
public class GetProductData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);

    GetProductData(String str) {            
          try {
              qryText= URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8");              
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
        Dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        Dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(getProductData());
            ProductList=new ArrayList<String>();
            Status = json.getBoolean("Status");
            if (Status) {                   
                JSONArray Products=json.getJSONArray("Products");                   
                if (Products.length() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject ProductObj = Products.getJSONObject(i);                      
                        ProductList.add("  "+ProductObj.getString("Name"));
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Error = json.getString("Message");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Error = e.getMessage();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        Dialog.dismiss();
        if (Error != null) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Some Error Occured : " + Error,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
                try {
                    ArrayAdapter<String> Arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,ProductList);   
                    Arrayadapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);                   
                    autoComplete.setAdapter(Arrayadapter); 
                    autoComplete.showDropDown();
                    autoComplete.requestFocus();

                    autoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {                    
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                           int position, long id) {
                            itemselected=true;
                            String itemstr=ProductList.get(position).trim();
                            autoComplete.setText(itemstr);
                        }
                   }); 

                   // ItemName.setSelected(selected)

                } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }
}
```